# Core Animation cross-dissolve between one string (or image) and another when changing bound value?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I have an NSTextView and an NSImageView that is bound to a NSString and an NSImage in my code.  I would like to have the displayed string and image cross-dissolve when I change the string and image in code.  Any way to do this?  Do I need to stop using bindings?  (And if I do, is there any trick to getting the string and the image to cross-dissolve when I change the value, or do I have to do something weird like fade it out and fade a new one back in?)

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those classes offer any kind of transition by animator proxy.

Something similar has been asked for NSImageView alone, but I suppose it could be applied to an NSTextView as well. Essentially, add/remove to/from the superview via the animator proxy.

[How can I animate a content switch in an NSImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795882/how-can-i-animate-a-content-switch-in-an-nsimageview)

I don't believe Bindings would get along with this.